# Underclocking (overclocking) Nvidia card

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, xorg, overclocking

I have a GTX295 Nvidia card which sadly won't run on stock clock frequencies any more, I did a brief inspection of the PCB and reapplied the TMI. It just turns itself off for some odd reason after 2-3 minutes in games, though benchmarks run perfectly fine even if overclocked.

Anyway I switched from Windows to Linux for reasons. In windows there were applications made by the card manufacturers that allowed you to adjust whatever you wanted, pretty much, in Linux however this is not as simple as I had hoped. I switched to a proprietary driver, 304 I believe, followed instructions on how to do the Xorg.conf with Coolbits 'hack' which unfortunately resulted in no change at all. I couldn't get NVclock working too.

Doing research I read multiple times that they pulled overclocking ability on Linux. I'm not exactly sure whether that is true. Playing games such as Team Fortress 2 with the Nouveau driver results in a blank screen, the proprietary one works good enough, but I can't enjoy a game for more than 5 minutes due to the card being broken.

I haven't done something like that on a Linux machine ever before and I would appreciate guidance in my quest. If possible please provide a driver that would work for me and any additional instructions in case I've being doing something wrong. Oh and I'm not exactly sure if I generated a xorg.conf file correctly, I've been told just to make a new one and insert a few lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to get it working properly this time. Using 313.30 and I made a new xorg.conf file with the following in it:

```
 Section "Device"

 Identifier    "Default Device"
 Option  "Coolbits" "1"
 Option  "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x222PowerMizerLevel=0x3;PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x3"
  Driver  "nvidia"
  Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
  EndSection
```

Comment: Run from terminal 

    sudo nvidia-settings

, can you see options?